How to Reboot Server through GraphQL commands
I want to reboot my server using GraphQL code but I keep getting error messages.
On my servers playground page http://MY_IP/graphql
I entered this code:
mutation {
  auth {
    login(username: "MY_USERNAME", password: "MY_PASSWORD") {
      ... on Error {
        message
        __typename
      }
      __typename
    }
  }
  
  bos {
    reboot {
      ... on Error {
        message
        __typename
      }
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
}

This is the error code I get:
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unauthorized access",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 11,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "bos"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "UNAUTHORIZED"
      }
    }
  ]
}

I expected to log into my server and then reboot my server but it didn't reboot. I'm not even sure if I logged into the server.
